# Uploading test build To iTunes Connect before integrating GameCenter confusion

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Before I upload my xcode project for testing purposes so far, do I have to integrate Game Center's Leaderboards and iAd first for my game app or can I upload my xcode build for sandbox testing and then integrate Game Center and iAd through that uploaded project?

I want to test Game Center with Sandbox testing but don't know if I can upload my xcode project first and then put in Game Center and then do sandbox testing through that upload? Or Once I upload to testing, I can't change any code in xcode project?

Answer (score 0):

I would upload it to TestFlight to get the review ball rolling by adding one or two internal testers and submitting your first build.

The tutorials and documentation needed to accomplish this are at:

- https://developer.apple.com/testflight/update/

Once you've gotten your first rejection or approval out of the way, shoot for one update a week for one month to get a hang of things and how long reviews take.